# Android navigation bar overllaping popupmenu

Tags: android, menu, popup, overlap

The images says by itself:

## That image bellow is on a Galaxy Ace 2 (2.3), **it works fine**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Th3x.png "Works fine"

## That image bellow is on a Nexus4 (4.3), system's navigation bar is overllaping the popupmenu:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnHrH.png "System bar trolling me"

This is the code snippet i use to show the popup:

```
//totalHeight = a complex calculation;
pop.setHeight(totalHeight);
pop.setWidth((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.popup_width));
pop.showAsDropDown((View) threeDotsButton.getParent());
```

As you can see, the system navigation bar os overllaping the popup menu. Any guesses?

Comment: It may be that the problem is in **'a complex calculation'**

Comment: No definetly not. As you can see, the problem is only on devices with system bar. The "complex calculation" just calculate the height of the popup.